# ajax file download from facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to download a file from facebook, for example

> https://www.facebook.com/download/847027648649013/36654984.doc

using jquery's ajax (not to disk, to js variable...).

since this is for debug purposes i disabled my chrome's 'same origin policy' using -allow-file-access-from-files -disable-web-security

the problem is - im getting 404 while if i put this link in a new browser tab ill get 302 and then a redirect to the actual file.

how would i download this file?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using a php proxy.

using php's curl solved both sop problem (no need for -disable-web-security) and does the redirect automatically. now i only need to parse the result....

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the file using a jquery get function.

The site you are trying to get the file can not container a No Access-Control-Allow-Orign header,

If it does you will recieve the following javascript error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/download/847027648649013/36654984.doc".  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

If you have permission to access the file from another domain or from a file not hosted in the same domain in other words you can you use the following JQuery code:

```
         var url = "https://www.facebook.com/download/847027648649013/36654984.doc";


      $.get(url,
              function(data){



                //store the file contents in the result variable
                var result = data;




             });
```

Comment: as i said, sop was not my problem, as i disabled it, ans was able do do ajax get to another file, but not to facebook, probably because of the redirect